# Javascript/Jquery Object Literal version, perform function on variable request

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I have this code:

```
var ST = {
         city: 'a#cityId:eq(2)',
         state: 'div.location:eq(1)',
         zip: 'p#zipcodes:eq(3)',
         people: 'div.population :input',
         autoload: function(selector) {
                 var elem = $(selector).get(0);
                 if (!elem || elem == 'undefined' || elem.length == '0') {
                         return false;
                 }
                 return elem;
         },
};
```

Can I request the variable City for example, and have it automatically executed through autoload function?

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

```
ST.city ? ST.city.click() : '';
```

Comment: The selectors used will only result in ONE element (`a#cityId`) so including `:eq(2)` on the end will return no results.

Comment: You can execute the function like this `ST.autoload();`

Comment: @Mottie `a#cityId` selector will select all the `a` elements that have id of `cityId`.

Comment: ID's should be unique... jQuery will only return one element

Comment: @Mottie Yes, IDs must be unique, and _ID_ selector returns the first matched element, but `a#cityId !== #cityId`. http://jsfiddle.net/Qqh5Q/

Comment: ok, but even `a#cityId` will only return one result

Comment: @Mottie Can you provide an example?

Comment: @undefined: `a#cityId` will only return 0 or 1 results, so `:eq(2)` is always going to be unsatisfied, so `a#cityId:eq(2)` is a pointless selector, it will never match anything **in a valid document**. Using the same `id` on more than one element results in an **invalid** document. The behavior of a selector engine on invalid documents is undefined. It could throw an error, it could return just the first, it could return just the last, or it could return all of them. It's undefined. (No pun!)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Well, I agree, that selector doesn't make sense and the OP's document is invalid if it has duplicate IDs. But in my Chrome (v36) browser `$('a#cityId:eq(2)')` selects the third element as expected, http://jsfiddle.net/3K3kc/. My point was that, as you say, it doesn't always return 0 or 1 element.

Comment: @undefined: My point was that *you can't count on what it returns*. The behavior is undefined. What you describe is what it does with Chrome's selector engine, but you can't know whether that will be true in the next dot release of Chrome, or in Firefox, or...

Comment: @undefined Try that same demo using jQuery 1.6.4...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Actually, I believe this is how jQuery's Sizzle engine work and is not (necessarily) browser-specific. Am I wrong in saying that?

Comment: @undefined because it works now, doesn't mean it won't break in the future. If this point is brought up to the jQuery team, maybe they will realize that this is an issue and correct it thereby breaking the selectors used here. Bottom line is that ID's are meant to be unique; follow that rule and your code won't break in the future.

Comment: @Mottie Well, I don't use duplicate IDs in my documents. But thanks for your input. All I wanted to say was that it doesn't always return 0 or 1 element.

Comment: @undefined: Sizzle will defer to the browser's selector engine if it can. That *specific* selector will use Sizzle's code, you're right, because it uses jQuery's (Sizzle's) `:eq`, but even so, the next update to Sizzle could change it. The general case, say `a#cityId.foo`, would be offloaded to the browser's selector engine.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for your inputs. Then, what will be the point of using a selector library if it can't solve the inconsistencies? Maybe I'm missing something. Sorry, I didn't want it to be a long discussion which is not related to the main problem in the question.

Comment: @undefined: The point *was* to have a selector library at all. Now, years later, browsers expose their selector engines via `querySelector`/`querySelectorAll`, so there's a *lot* less need for Sizzle now. :-) (Even IE8 has QSA.)

Comment: It was just an example, it was actually a div, not an anchor... sorry for the headache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to just do `ST.city.click()` without worrying about whether anything matches the selector, stick with using a jQuery set rather than trying to use the DOM element directly.

If you can rely on having `Object.defineProperty` (support is currently *reasonable*, but it's not in IE8 for normal objects for instance), you can do this:

```
var ST = {};
Object.defineProperties(ST, {
    "city": {
        get: function() {
            return $('a#cityId:eq(2)'); // (But see Mottie's note about this selector)
        }
    },
    "state": {
        get: function() {
            return $('div.location:eq(1)');
        }
    },
    // ...and so on
});
```

Since the getters for the properties return jQuery sets, you can happily call `click` on them even if they're empty:

```
ST.city.click();
```

The above can be make briefer, I left it verbose for clarity. Here's the short version:

```
var ST = {
    city: 'a#cityId:eq(2)',
    state: 'div.location:eq(1)',
    zip: 'p#zipcodes:eq(3)',
    people: 'div.population :input'
};
$.each(ST, function(key, value) {
    Object.defineProperty(ST, key, {
        get: function() {
            return $(value);
        }
    });
});
```

But if you need to support older browsers, you'll need a function call. You could make `ST` itself the function:

```
var ST = function(selector) {
    return $(ST.selectors[selector]);
};
ST.selectors = {
    city: 'a#cityId:eq(2)',
    state: 'div.location:eq(1)',
    zip: 'p#zipcodes:eq(3)',
    people: 'div.population :input'
};
```

Usage:

```
ST('city').click();
```

Or make a property on `ST` the function:

```
var ST = {
    city: 'a#cityId:eq(2)',
    state: 'div.location:eq(1)',
    zip: 'p#zipcodes:eq(3)',
    people: 'div.population :input',
    autoload: function(selector) {
        return $(this[selector]);
    }
};
```

Usage:

```
ST.autoload('city').click();
```

Comment: I suppose i could have all selectors defined in one object, and iterate with Object.defineProperty assigning the autoload function, i'll give a try. But i need a false answer if the element doesn't exist.

Comment: @Ionut: But you can't call `click` on `false`. You said you wanted to do `ST.city.click()`, there's no check there, that's why I used a jQuery object, so you could do that without the check.

Comment: i verify before clicking:
       ST.city ? ST.city.click() : '';

Comment: @Ionut: Huh, I could have sworn it was just `ST.city.click()` when I originally read the question. My question to you is: Why? Why do the extra work? I mean, you can, and I can update the answer to show how, but...it's just extra work.

Comment: Some elements are not for clicking and some elements do not exist until other elements are clicked.

Comment: @Ionut: The ones that don't exist are a non-issue (again: if you call `click` on an empty jQuery set, nothing happens). The ones that are not for clicking...don't call `click` on...? You can always easily tell whether a jQuery set is empty, if that's the real reason for wanting `false`: `if (!ST.city[0]) { /* It's empty */ }`

Comment: Also another question please, some elements work only with get(0) - from my google friend seems i need the RAW element version for my click to work, how would i make the iteration safe ? ..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58580/discussion-between-ionut-and-t-j-crowder).

Comment: (I don't do the chat thing if it's germane to the question.) Your google friend is probably mistaken. :-) When you call `click` on a jQuery instance, the `click` event is fired on the first element in the set, like this: A) If jQuery has any handlers attached to the element, it fires them; B) Then jQuery calls the `click` method of the DOM element (using a flag to remind itself not to call its handlers again when it sees the resulting event). (That's the current behavior; I don't know if several versions back there may have been something else).

Comment: Well i tried all kind of workarounds to get the element clicked since the expected "click" didn't work, by using document.evaluate worked but the most simple was the .get(0) . I did dumped the element and had a onclick handler but still shot blind bullets.

Comment: @Ionut: What version of jQuery are you using? Again, with any recent version, calling jQuery's `click` **will** call the DOM element's click.

Comment: I used Visual Event and found that the not-working click had an event listener using "this.", perhaps it used my caller for "this." ..  i don't if that's the cause, or if my jquery selector returned multiple elements, but adding ST.city[0].click worked. PS:jquery-2.1.1.min.js

Answer (score 0):

```
ST.autoload(ST.city) ? $(ST.city).click() : "";
```